# Problem moving Wordpress site from one server to another

Tags: php, wordpress

I moved an existing wordpress site from one server to another.

But when I run it shows database connection error.

In which file do we specify new database related information in Wordpress?

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database configuration details are located in `wp-config.php` in the root Wordpress directory.

Comment: Ok.Thanks. So only thing I need to do is modify the file. No need to compile...right?

Comment: No, PHP is an interpreted language.  No need to compile.  (The only minor exception to this is if you're using APC or some other opcode cacher and have configured it to not `stat` the filesystem to check for file changes, in which case you'd need to `SIGHUP` the PHP processes.  You would know if this was the case.)

Comment: Even after making the database info change, it still gives "Error establishing a database connection"...what could be wrong?

Comment: Any number of things, the most likely that whatever authentication details you are using are incorrect.  Have you confirmed that the user and password you are using have been created on the new server with the appropriate hostname (usually 'localhost') and that they have been granted full privileges to the database holding your Wordpress data?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official how to for doing this. You'll need to move the files, the database, and likely you'll have to change the hostname in wp-config.

**http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_to_a_New_Server**